# Ceiling LED lamp blinks

Tags: lighting

After  a few months of installed my Home Depot round ceiling LED lamp started to act like its being possessed. After turning it On, it goes Off and On repeatedly. Sometimes after a few minutes it stays On. Lately it doesn't stay On.
Any ideas why this happen?
Thank you

Comment: See if you can get it exchanged.  I have that fixture in my laundry room and have had no problems, however several people have had issues. I can remember at least two questions similar to yours.  The drivers gone bad.  It actually is a cheap Chinese version, I haven’t had any problems with mine though.

Comment: The LED unit is most likely defective. Take it back or contact company for warranty replacement.

Comment: Since it's only a few months old you should be able to take it back to Home Depot. They are very good about exchanges. Even if you don't have your receipt but purchased this item with a credit card they will more than likely credit a refund back to your card or even better, provide you with a hassle free exchange. With these LED inexpensive lights sometimes you get a lemon. But when you buy from big box stores like HD they typically take good care of you. I also would suggest looking up the exact model on their webpage. If it has a poor rating consider upgrading to a better model.

Answer (score 1):

The LED driver is most likely faulty. You should be able to take the whole lamp back for replacement or refund.